is it safe to swap vector in multi thread?
i  am currently working on multi thread cctv system. i create a variable
vector<cv::Mat> all_camera_frame
in the main thread. Than i pass the element to different thread .for each thread it create a local variable cv::Mat frame to get the frame from camera than copy the frame to the buffer. To speed up i use std::swap(all_camera_frame[0], frame); instead of  all_camera_frame[0] = frames.clone(); .it work but i wonder if it is safe? i check the swap function find that it swap the element pointer and the mata data, but one is on the heap one is on the stack, what will happened if thread end ? will it cause segmentation fault cause main thread element is now something creat by thread but already been destory?
this is the function i have now. it work fine even if the frame_buffers and fram_renew is a local parameter create in a sub thread. it is ok to swap a local parameter with a gobal parameter. because it swap the matadata not the pointer to matadata. see from the commont i find that it is not atomic so lock is needed i add lock to the function.
void collect_frames_from_buffers(std::vector<cv::Mat> &frames, 
                                 std::vector<int> &frame_update,
                                 std::vector<cv::Mat> &frame_buffers,
                                 std::vector<int> &frame_renew,
                                 std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::mutex>> &set_of_frame_mutex_ptr)
{
    size_t num_cameras = frames.size();

    // Ensure that the number of mutexes matches the number of cameras
    if (set_of_frame_mutex_ptr.size() != num_cameras) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Insufficient number of mutexes provided.");
    }

    // Create a vector to hold the unique locks
    std::vector<std::unique_lock<std::mutex>> locks;
    locks.reserve(num_cameras);

    // Acquire all locks in a consistent order to avoid deadlocks
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_cameras; ++i) {
        if (set_of_frame_mutex_ptr[i]) { // Check if the unique_ptr is not null
            locks.emplace_back(*set_of_frame_mutex_ptr[i]);
        }
        else {
            throw std::runtime_error("Mutex pointer is null for camera index " + std::to_string(i));
        }
    }

    // Now all buffers are locked, proceed to swap
    std::swap(frames, frame_buffers);
    std::swap(frame_update, frame_renew);

    // Locks will be automatically released when they go out of scope
}


rather than describing your code you should show it. Read about [mcve]

swap is not atomic => you have a race condtion => UB (undefined behavior).

though, = isnt thread safe either. You cannot let multiple threads write to all_camera_frame[0] without synchronization.

What would be ok is each thread writing a different element of all_camera_frame, e.g. thread 0 writes to all_camera_frame[0], thread 1 writes to all_camera_frame[1] etc

Your code is unsafe with both of your methods if more than one thread attempts to modify all_camera_frame[0].   Assignment is not an atomic operation for any type (e.g. int, or compound types such as structs or classes, other than explicitly atomic types, such as std::atomic<int>. Swapping is also not atomic. The problem with unsafe code is that it may pass testing but eventually/intermittently fail in the hands of an end user(e.g. there is a non-zero likelihood that a test involving series of unsafe operations will produce the same results that would be expected of safe operations).

If an answer solves your problem @lessthanenough you could click '✔' to mark it as an accepted answer. You can also upvote any helpful answer, as voting and accepting is separate (see here: What should I do when someone answers my question?).


is it safe to swap vector in multi thread?

No. It is not safe at all.
std::swap is not an atomic operation.
Using it in a multi threaded environment requires using some form of thread synchronization mechanism (e.g. a std::mutex).
Otherwise you have a race condition which results in UB (undefined behavior).
This means anything can happen, including (but not necessairly) a segmentation fault.
The program might even seem to work properly but you cannot rely on that.
A side note:
Assignment of a cv::Mat is not atomic either.
In both cases you need to use some form of thread-synchronization mechanism.

if i use lock to protect the swap operation like above code, is it save ? can i use it to replace .clone()?

If you access the frames from another thread, you also have to lock it there (it's not enough to lock only when swapping). Whenever 2 or more threads access the same resource, you have to synchronize the access.
